# one to many relationships and delete cascades

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, foreign-keys

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

I have three tables, A, M, Z.

Table A has a 1 to many relationship with the table M. It also has a delete cascade on the foreign key

Table Z is a new table and it should also have a 1 to many relationship with table M, again there should be a delete cascade on the foreign key.

I take it my designed is flawed? Because if I delete a record from table A the corresponding records in table M will be deleted but I'm guessing this will break the relationship between table M & Z? Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both constraints are defined as `on delete cascade`, the relationship won't break - the delete will cascade. When you delete from `A` all the corresponding records of `M` will be deleted, and for each record in `M`, all the records in `Z` will be deleted.

EDIT:
Based on the conversation in the comments, I misunderstood the question.
The correct situation is that `A` is a parent table, and `M` and `Z` are both, independently, its children.
In this case, deleting from `A` will delete from both `M` and `Z`, cascading down the relevant constraints. Deleting tom `M` or `Z` will not affect the other tables.

Comment: oh thats handy! I take it you delete data from table M directly nothing with happen to either table A or Z?

Comment: @mHelpMe If you delete from `M` it will cascade to `Z`, but will not affect `A`.

Comment: I don't follow why would deleting from M cascade to Z? In my mind A has 1 to many with M & Z has a 1 to many with M. So I would expect if you deleted data from table M that either nothing happens to either Z or A or happens to both not just one of the tables?

Comment: @mHelpMe your relationship is `a->[1:n]->m->[1:n]->z`. In this design, `A` is `M`'s parent, which is in turn `Z`'s parent. So deleting from `M` will cascade down to `Z`, but not up to`A`.

Comment: sorry maybe my post wasn't very clear but I want a relationship a->[1:n]->m & seperatley z->[1:n]->m

Comment: @mHelpMe in that case, I misunderstood the situation. Only deleting from `A` will cascade the constraints, as you suggested - see my clarifying edit.